# Azure Toolkit for Eclipse buttons and "Sign in" not working

Tags: azure-java-tools

Azure Toolkit for Eclipse: v.3.25.0
Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
JDK: 16

After I managed to install the package, the buttons are shown in the up menu but none of them seem to work. I tried doing it with a fresh copy of Eclipse, with no previous projects and this window appears in the right bottom corner even though the buttons do not work:
[image: Azure explorer]

The only button that works here is the highlighted one:
[image: Sign in button]

and this opens:
[image: Sign in form]

but when I'm trying to Sign in, it looks like the process fails.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed already, please try out the latest plugin version like https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/releases/tag/azure-eclipse-toolkit-V3.27.0